# Looking for a HttpUtility.ParseQueryString alternative

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-runtime, query-string

Is there an alternative for this method in the Windows Runtime?

If not is there any elegant way to parse a query string from an URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task there is a
`WwwFormUrlDecoder.GetFirstValueByName()` method in Windows RT.

[MSDN: WwwFormUrlDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.wwwformurldecoder)